# check for existence of xml file in different folders with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to check if a file exists in any of the preceding folders and if not, write that filename to the output:

So my folder structure looks like this:

```
FOLDER_A
a.xml
b.xml
c.xml
d.xml

FOLDER_B
c.xml
d.xml
e.xml

FOLDER_C
d.xml
e.xml
f.xml
g.xml

FOLDER_D
e.xml
f.xml
g.xml
```

Desired output:

```
<files>
<file>a.xml</file>
<file>b.xml</file>
<file>c.xml</file>
<file>d.xml</file>
<file>e.xml</file>
<file>f.xml</file>
<file>g.xml</file>
</files>
```

My attempt so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <files>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </files>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="folders">
        <xsl:for-each select="folder">
            <xsl:variable name="numberOfFolders" select="count(preceding-sibling::folder)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="nameOfPrecedingFolder" select="preceding-sibling::folder/@name"/>
            <xsl:variable name="string" select="iri-to-uri(concat(@name, '/?select=*.xml'))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="input" select="collection($string)"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="$input">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$numberOfFolders = 0">
                        <file>
                            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
                        </file>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>

                        <xsl:variable name="currInput" select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="currFolder" select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()-1]"/>

                        <xsl:for-each select="$nameOfPrecedingFolder">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="doc-available(iri-to-uri(concat(.,'/',$currInput))) = fn:false()"></xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise><file><xsl:value-of select="$currInput"/></file></xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem that I have is that I dont know how to code the OR-condition. Right now, it checks each folder individually an if the file doesnt exist in that folder, it writes it to the output, regardless of whether it already exists in another previous folder.

How can I get it to consider all of the previous folders and not write the file to the output if that files exists in any one of those folders?

Help and tips highly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you show us the XML input structure? If you simply want to find distinct file names then I would expect you to use the `distinct-values` function or `for-each-group`, e.g. somehow `distinct-values(for $fileName in /folders/folder/uri-collection(iri-to-uri(concat(@name, '/?select=*.xml'))) return tokenize($fileName, '/')[last()])`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! There isnt really an input xml... it's folders with xml files in them. I'll try your suggestion the next days, when I have time to get back to this!

Comment: I expect most XSLT experts here have the same thought in mind that I do -- what the xxxx do you *mean* there's no input XML? This makes absolutely no sense to me. What XSLT processor are you using, and how do you expect it to magically understand filesystems?