# check if xml file exists with XSLT 2.0, saxon9HE

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to check, whether a file exists, with xslt 2.0. However, it's not working. I've tried this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="doc(iri-to-uri(concat($currFolder, '/', $currSubFolder, '/', @href)))">
```

(The path is correct)

however, this results in an error, when the file isnt there.

and this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="doc-available(iri-to-uri(concat($currFolder, '/', $currSubFolder, '/', @href)))">
```

doesn't work, it tells me files are there that clearly don't exist.

Whats the correct way to do this? A reliable way to check, if an xml file exists.

Comment: Can you state the exact version of Saxon 9 HE that fails with the `doc-available` test?

Comment: I downloaded the latest jar from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/, so I assume it is Saxon HE 9.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769589/check-for-existence-of-xml-file-in-different-folders-with-xslt), the author mentions that something such as this worked for them as far as checking for the existence of an xml file.

> Right now, it checks each folder individually an if the file doesnt exist in that folder, it writes it to the output, regardless of whether it already exists in another previous folder.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:variable name="currInput" select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="doc-available(iri-to-uri(concat(.,'/',$currInput))) = fn:false()"></xsl:when>
```